# testing routes with subdomain constraints using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm having trouble getting my rspec routing tests working with a subdomain constraint.

Specifically I have a route

```
constraints :subdomain => "api" do
  resources :sign_ups, :only => [:create]
end
```

and (among others) a test

```
it "does allow creation of sign ups" do
  {:post => "/sign_ups"}.should route_to(
    :controller => "sign_ups",
    :action => "create",
  )
end
```

If I remove the subdomain constraint this test passes, but with it it fails. I have to tell rspec to use the subdomain but I'm at a loss as to how

TIA

Andy

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I usually do:

```
let(:url)     { "http://api.domain.com"     }
let(:bad_url) { "http://bad_url.domain.com" }

it "does allow creation of sign ups" do
  {:post => "#{url}/sign_ups"}.should route_to(
   :controller => "sign_ups",
   :action => "create",
  )
end

it "should not route" do
  {:post => "#{bad_url}/sign_ups"}.should_not route_to(
   :controller => "sign_ups",
   :action => "create",
  )
end
```

Comment: I remember this information was not obvious and I had some pain to get it ;)

Comment: Crikey, this seems like a lot of work if you're changing an existing app.

Comment: Nice, do you know how to set the Accept header via this method?

Comment: In my rails 4 app with current rspec this doesn't work. Does it need to be additionally configured? I got an error: "no routes matches for <<url>>"

I used allowed subdomain with 'lvh.me' and 'local.dev' (the last one was implemented in my /etc/hosts file)

Comment: Fixed - the slash at the end of url is not allowed.

Comment: I am trying to solve exactly same problem. But I don't understand what we need to put in place for `domain.com`. Or do I have to configure it some where ?

Comment: Updated response for Rails 4 and later versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109356/how-to-test-subdomain-constraint-with-rspec-rails-4