# Testing routes with subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to test my routes with subdomain but I don't know how exactly to test it. My subdomain is working fine, I am just having difficulty passing current request with subdomain.

Below are my routes:

```
search_finances GET    /finances/search(.:format)                     finances#search {:subdomain=>"admin"}
  search_finance_finances POST   /finances/search_finance(.:format)             finances#search_finance {:subdomain=>"admin"}
           delete_finance GET    /finances/:id/delete(.:format)                 finances#delete {:subdomain=>"admin"}
                 finances GET    /finances(.:format)                            finances#index {:subdomain=>"admin"}
                          POST   /finances(.:format)                            finances#create {:subdomain=>"admin"}
              new_finance GET    /finances/new(.:format)                        finances#new {:subdomain=>"admin"}
             edit_finance GET    /finances/:id/edit(.:format)                   finances#edit {:subdomain=>"admin"}
                  finance GET    /finances/:id(.:format)                        finances#show {:subdomain=>"admin"}
                          PATCH  /finances/:id(.:format)                        finances#update {:subdomain=>"admin"}
                          PUT    /finances/:id(.:format)                        finances#update {:subdomain=>"admin"}
                          DELETE /finances/:id(.:format)                        finances#destroy {:subdomain=>"admin"}
                          GET    /finances/search_finance/:page(.:format)       finances#search_finance {:subdomain=>"admin"}
```

Below is snippets for my routing test

`spec/routing/finances_routing_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe FinancesController do
  describe 'routing' do
    it 'routes to #index' do
      expect(get: '/finances').to route_to('finances#index')
    end
  end
end
```

Below is my error message:

```
1) FinancesController routing routes to #index
     Failure/Error: expect(get: '/finances').to route_to('finances#index')
       No route matches "/finances"
```

How can I pass subdomain in my test? I looked for other examples on stackoverflow about setting `reqest.host = admin.example.com` but that didn't work for me ( I may be doing something wrong )

Updated:

I tried to use this solution [testing routes with subdomain constraints using rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329669/testing-routes-with-subdomain-constraints-using-rspec?rq=1)

But I don't understand where to set up `domain`.