# Best practices for redirecting to bare domain Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redirect, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a site hosted on Heroku. For SEO purposes I am trying to use strictly my bare domain (https://example.com/).

I found [this medium article](https://medium.com/@mikekitson/redirecting-to-a-bare-domain-in-rails-5-7fe533df225f) suggesting to insert this code into `routes.rb`

```
match '(*any)', to: redirect(subdomain: ''), via: :all, constraints: {subdomain: 'www'}
```

Seems like a easy and efficient way to handle redirecting to bare domain in Rails.

However, now all my tests are failing with the message:

```
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://example.com/>.
```

And

```
Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <301: Moved Permanently> redirect to <http://example.com/>
```

I can somewhat fix this by replacing `assert_response :success` with `assert_response :redirect` in my test logic for page loads.

My question is, would changing all my tests to `assert_response :response` be best practice? Or is there an easier way to configure bare domain redirects in Rails 6 that does not interfere with test logic?

Example of test:

```
  test "should get example page" do
    get example_path
    assert_response :success
  end
```

Routes.rb

```
 root to: "site#index"

 get "example", to: "site#example
```

Comment: It seems your test requests include the `www.` subdomain, triggering the redirect. Can you include more about these tests? (e.g. what testing framework, an example of the test that's failing, what route you're requesting, etc). You should be able to change your tests to not use the `www.` subdomain.

Comment: can you add the relevant `routes` definition for the example path?

Comment: Added the `routes` definition above

Comment: I'm not sure why the get request is hitting your redirect route w/ the `www` constraint. Using the `_path` like you're doing shouldn't know to use a subdomain constraint, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329669/testing-routes-with-subdomain-constraints-using-rspec

Comment: My guess would be there's code that is setting the host manually to `www.example.com` in your test setup, something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556627/rails-rspec-set-subdomain/30413528#30413528

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the default URL used for rails testing happens to be `www.example.com`, which is hitting your route.

See more details here [How do I change the default "www.example.com" domain for testing in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598933/how-do-i-change-the-default-www-example-com-domain-for-testing-in-rails)

This hits your redirect route. Change the default host to remove the `www` and it should fix the problem, e.g.

```
controller.request.host = "example.com"
```